# How do you change a string that is already in the console?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to make a typing thingy where you type what time delay you would like and what the string you want to output is and then it slowly types each letter:

```
import time

l = float(input('What is the time delay you would like? '))

def thing(i):
    y = 0
    for x in range(len(i)):
        print(i[y])
        time.sleep(l)
        y += 1
thing(input('What would you like to output? '))
```

I just have one problem. I want the string to output in one line but each letter at a different time, but I can only make it so that it outputs each letter on a different line. Can someone tell me if there is a way to make it so that it is on the same line, like one letter at .1 seconds another at .2?

Comment: `print(i[y], end='')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default ending for the built in `print` function is "\n".

You can change the default behavior by providing an alternative string to the `end` keyword argument.

For example.

```
print('hello' end='')
print(' world!')
```

The output would be `hello world!`

for your specific example:

```
import time

l = float(input('What is the time delay you would like? '))

def thing(i):
    y = 0
    for x in range(len(i)):
        print(i[y], end='')
        time.sleep(l)
        y += 1
thing(input('What would you like to output? '))
```